# move visible items to beginning of index

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of elements which are positioned absolutely across an image.
I created a filter to hide/show elements, which is working, but I want to move the shown items to be the first children in the container, otherwise there would just be empty spaces when the previous items have "disappeared" when the filter was activated.
If I would be able to do that, I could use CSS to define the absolute position according to :first-of-type, :nth-of-type(2) etc - so that always the first children are positioned where I want them.

The code is:

```
$(".trigger-filter").click(function() {
  var filterData = $(this).attr("data-filter");
  if (filterData == "all") {
    $(".team").show("2000");
  } else {
    $(".team").not("." + filterData).hide("2000");
    $(".team").filter("." + filterData).show("2000");
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="team-filters">
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="tarya-fintech">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-610.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="management">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-104-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="marketing">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-57-2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="legal">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-184-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="tarya-holding">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-73.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="finance">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-56-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="underwriting">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-95-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="back-office">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-183-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="customer-service">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-103-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="customer-success">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-72-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="collection">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-185-2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="business-development">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-182-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="tarya-ukraine">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-545.png">
  </div>
  <div class="trigger-filter" data-filter="all">
    <img src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Group-72222222.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="team-body">
  <div class="team-image">
    <img class="desktop-img" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/clean.png">
  </div>


  <div class="team eran-yogev tarya-fintech">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev tarya-fintech">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev tarya-ukraine">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev tarya-ukraine">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev collection">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev collection">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev customer-success">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev back-office">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev underwriting">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev finance">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev finance">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev tarya-holding">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev legal">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev legal">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev marketing">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="team eran-yogev management">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Eran-1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .team-body {
    position: relative;
  }

  .team-filters img {
    background: #dbdbdb;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .team-filters {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .checked-circle {
    filter: none !important;
  }


  .team-image {
    position: relative;
  }

  .team-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .team-picture {
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }


  .team,
  .team-cat {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
  }

  .eran-yogev {
    top: 0.4%;
    left: 44.4%;
    width: 8.5%;
  }

  .shlomi-frenkel {
    top: 0.2%;
    left: 62.4%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .roy-shenbaum {
    top: 3.6%;
    left: 53.1%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .giora-olmert {
    top: 4.95%;
    left: 41.4%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .iris-keret {
    top: 6.75%;
    left: 16.6%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .tamar-levine {
    top: 2.3%;
    left: 73.2%;
    width: 12.6%;
  }

  .mikhail-geoui {
    top: 7.75%;
    left: 28.6%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .elyah-salomon {
    top: 11.95%;
    left: 7%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .nitzan-alcobi {
    top: 10.4%;
    left: 43%;
    width: 15.1%;
  }

  .bianca-meger {
    top: 16.55%;
    left: 19.5%;
    width: 14.1%;
  }

  .tal-rave {
    top: 8.35%;
    left: 68%;
    width: 10.4%;
  }

  .liav-david {
    top: 22%;
    left: 41.4%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .eliad-zefania {
    top: 25.65%;
    left: 26%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .avner-erez {
    top: 16.5%;
    left: 37%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .assaf-shlush {
    top: 27.6%;
    left: 14.9%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .liran-brecher {
    top: 25.6%;
    left: 69.2%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .shahaf-erlich {
    top: 27.3%;
    left: 45.9%;
    width: 11.5%;
  }

  .arnon-lempert {
    top: 14.3%;
    left: 71%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .ron-nitzan {
    top: 32.9%;
    left: 52%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .shay-butbul {
    top: 30.1%;
    left: 75.7%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .iris-yogev {
    top: 29.7%;
    left: 88.55%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .limor-baranes {
    top: 35.5%;
    left: 15.3%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .liat-raz-rubin {
    top: 33%;
    left: 2.3%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .eyal-elhayany {
    top: 32.35%;
    left: 37.7%;
    width: 12.4%;
  }

  .varda-lusthaus {
    top: 33%;
    left: 62.6%;
    width: 13.2%;
  }

  .keren-stern-avnon {
    top: 28.9%;
    left: 61.25%;
    width: 7.8%;
  }

  .liran-ram-arviv {
    top: 34.9%;
    left: 77.4%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .itay-ram {
    top: 34.5%;
    left: 88.9%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .michal-moses {
    top: 38.15%;
    left: 24.5%;
    width: 14.1%;
  }

  .alice-lachnish {
    top: 38.3%;
    left: 40.2%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .dan-wagner {
    top: 44%;
    left: 16.6%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .kobi-moshe {
    top: 45.8%;
    left: 28.7%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .natali-haziza {
    top: 51.4%;
    left: 69.1%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .david-eskenazi {
    top: 43.6%;
    left: 41.3%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .sharon-kraus {
    top: 57.9%;
    left: 71.3%;
    width: 14.1%;
  }

  .limor-levinstein {
    top: 43.4%;
    left: 82.6%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .efrat-biber {
    top: 59.2%;
    left: 1%;
    width: 16.2%;
  }

  .esti-barkish {
    top: 50.1%;
    left: 7%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .zivit-ruderfer {
    top: 63.75%;
    left: 26%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .noam-rubin-levi {
    top: 55.2%;
    left: 37%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .keren-katz {
    top: 60.6%;
    left: 41.3%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .mor-swisa {
    top: 67.3%;
    left: 58.3%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .yana-david {
    top: 64.4%;
    left: 67.7%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .daniel-mor-benisho {
    top: 65.3%;
    left: 15.1%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .rachel-kashkash {
    top: 66.9%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 13.8%;
  }

  .hen-zehavi {
    top: 68.9%;
    left: 88.2%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .magali-schuvaks {
    top: 66.8%;
    left: 78%;
    width: 8.1%;
  }

  .bianca-meger-33 {
    top: 75.8%;
    left: 52.7%;
    width: 13.7%;
  }

  .boris-pavlov {
    top: 73.8%;
    left: 87.1%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .sapir-avraham {
    top: 71.5%;
    left: 79%;
    width: 7.3%;
  }

  .ifat-cohen {
    top: 81.3%;
    left: 18.65%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .hila-manor {
    top: 72.5%;
    left: 68.6%;
    width: 7.8%;
  }

  .shimon-sabag {
    top: 75.7%;
    left: 55.7%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .nofar-michaeli {
    top: 71.4%;
    left: 53.3%;
    width: 7.8%;
  }

  .hadar-tamarkin {
    top: 81.2%;
    left: 69.7%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .perl-amichai {
    top: 72%;
    left: 42.3%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .dana-kopelman-haim {
    top: 74.4%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 11.1%;
  }

  .rostyslav-diachenko {
    top: 87%;
    left: 5.9%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .yair-ben-david {
    top: 76.9%;
    left: 39.6%;
    width: 13.8%;
  }

  .max-tokarev {
    top: 86%;
    left: 59.1%;
    width: 16.4%;
  }

  .yaniv-komemi {
    top: 80%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 14.4%;
  }

  .vitaliy-shkurenko {
    top: 87.1%;
    left: 84.2%;
    width: 13.9%;
  }

  .nati-kamhazi {
    top: 81.2%;
    left: 53.3%;
    width: 11.1%;
  }

  .oleh-osyka {
    top: 91.35%;
    left: 20.2%;
    width: 14.1%;
  }

  .vladyslav-martynov {
    top: 93%;
    left: 36.95%;
    width: 11.1%;
  }

  .nitzan-zeev {
    top: 57%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .roy-mor {
    top: 76%;
    left: 29%;
    width: 7.8%;
  }

  .frider-drorit {
    top: 70.3%;
    left: 16.2%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .bar-dayan {
    top: 42.9%;
    left: 54.6%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .talya-sharamy {
    top: 45.8%;
    left: 69.9%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .miki-ishai {
    top: 10%;
    left: 81%;
    width: 9.4%;
  }

  .andrey-pirogov {
    top: 5%;
    left: 88.3%;
    width: 11.1%;
  }

  .gadi-sade {
    top: 13.9%;
    left: 88.9%;
    width: 11%;
  }

  .ivo-segora {
    top: 5.5%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 13.5%;
  }

  .nitza-kaminsky {
    top: 70%;
    left: 27.5%;
    width: 11.1%;
  }

  .ofir-fouks {
    top: 86%;
    left: 76.4%;
    width: 7.4%;
  }


  .eran-yogev .team-overlay,
  .mikhail-geoui .team-overlay,
  .nitzan-alcobi .team-overlay,
  .avner-erez .team-overlay,
  .arnon-lempert .team-overlay,
  .eliad-zefania .team-overlay,
  .eyal-elhayany .team-overlay,
  .alice-lachnish .team-overlay,
  .keren-stern-avnon .team-overlay,
  .kobi-moshe .team-overlay,
  .noam-rubin-levi .team-overlay,
  .natali-haziza .team-overlay,
  .efrat-biber .team-overlay,
  .zivit-ruderfer .team-overlay,
  .perl-amichai .team-overlay,
  .hila-manor .team-overlay,
  .yaniv-komemi .team-overlay,
  .max-tokarev .team-overlay,
  .gadi-sade .team-overlay,
  .frider-drorit .team-overlay {
    background: rgba(105, 215, 222, 0.5);
  }

  .roy-shenbaum .team-overlay,
  .tal-rave .team-overlay,
  .bianca-meger .team-overlay,
  .shahaf-erlich .team-overlay,
  .liat-raz-rubin .team-overlay,
  .iris-yogev .team-overlay,
  .liran-ram-arviv .team-overlay,
  .rachel-kashkash .team-overlay,
  .sapir-avraham .team-overlay,
  .yair-ben-david .team-overlay,
  .hadar-tamarkin .team-overlay,
  .ifat-cohen .team-overlay,
  .vladyslav-martynov .team-overlay,
  .ivo-segora .team-overlay,
  .bar-dayan .team-overlay,
  .talya-sharamy .team-overlay {
    background: rgba(135, 40, 140, 0.5);
  }

  .tamar-levine .team-overlay,
  .assaf-shlush .team-overlay,
  .liran-brecher .team-overlay,
  .itay-ram .team-overlay,
  .yana-david .team-overlay,
  .daniel-mor-benisho .team-overlay,
  .nati-kamhazi .team-overlay,
  .vitaliy-shkurenko .team-overlay,
  .miki-ishai .team-overlay,
  .nitza-kaminsky .team-overlay,
  .roy-mor .team-overlay,
  .ofir-fouks .team-overlay {
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25);
  }


  @media (max-width: 767px) {

    .team-filters {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;
      display: block !important;
    }

    .team-image,
    .team-cat,
    .circle {
      display: none;
    }

    .all-of-them {
      background: url(http://outofsite.co.il/traya/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Android-Mobile-–-7-1.jpg);
      height: 5200px;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
    }

    .rtl .team-role,
    .rtl .team-role .en {
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 1;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .team-role,
    .team-role .en {
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 1;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .team:first-child,
    .team:nth-child(8n+1) {
      width: 19%;
      left: 27%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(2),
    .team:nth-child(8n+2) {
      width: 27%;
      left: 50%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(3),
    .team:nth-child(8n+3) {
      width: 27%;
      left: 20%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(4),
    .team:nth-child(8n+4) {
      width: 27%;
      left: 49%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(5),
    .team:nth-child(8n+5) {
      width: 25%;
      left: 26%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(6),
    .team:nth-child(8n+6) {
      width: 20%;
      left: 57%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(7),
    .team:nth-child(8n+7) {
      width: 31%;
      left: 25%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(8),
    .team:nth-child(8n+8) {
      width: 22%;
      left: 60%;
    }

    .team:first-of-type {
      top: 13px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(2) {
      top: 45px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(3) {
      top: 125px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(4) {
      top: 185px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(5) {
      top: 260px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(6) {
      top: 345px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(7) {
      top: 390px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(8) {
      top: 460px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(9) {
      top: 533px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(10) {
      top: 565px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(11) {
      top: 645px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(12) {
      top: 705px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(13) {
      top: 780px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(14) {
      top: 865px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(15) {
      top: 910px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(16) {
      top: 980px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(17) {
      top: 1053px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(18) {
      top: 1085px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(19) {
      top: 1165px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(20) {
      top: 1225px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(21) {
      top: 1300px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(22) {
      top: 1385px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(23) {
      top: 1430px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(24) {
      top: 1500px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(25) {
      top: 1573px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(26) {
      top: 1605px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(27) {
      top: 1685px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(28) {
      top: 1745px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(29) {
      top: 1820px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(30) {
      top: 1905px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(31) {
      top: 1950px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(32) {
      top: 2020px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(33) {
      top: 2093px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(34) {
      top: 2135px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(35) {
      top: 2205px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(36) {
      top: 2265px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(37) {
      top: 2340px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(38) {
      top: 2425px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(39) {
      top: 2470px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(40) {
      top: 2540px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(41) {
      top: 2613px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(42) {
      top: 2645px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(43) {
      top: 2725px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(44) {
      top: 2785px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(45) {
      top: 2860px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(46) {
      top: 2945px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(47) {
      top: 2990px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(48) {
      top: 3060px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(49) {
      top: 3133px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(50) {
      top: 3165px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(51) {
      top: 3245px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(52) {
      top: 3305px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(53) {
      top: 3380px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(54) {
      top: 3465px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(55) {
      top: 3510px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(56) {
      top: 3580px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(57) {
      top: 3653px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(58) {
      top: 3685px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(59) {
      top: 3765px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(60) {
      top: 3825px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(61) {
      top: 3900px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(62) {
      top: 3985px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(63) {
      top: 4030px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(64) {
      top: 4100px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(65) {
      top: 4173px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(66) {
      top: 4205px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(67) {
      top: 4285px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(68) {
      top: 4345px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(69) {
      top: 4420px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(70) {
      top: 4505px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(71) {
      top: 4550px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(72) {
      top: 4620px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(73) {
      top: 4693px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(74) {
      top: 4725px;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(75) {
      top: 4805px;
    }


    .trigger-filter[data-filter='tarya-fintech'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='marketing'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='legal'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='collection'] img.checked-circle {
      background: #03b9c4;
    }

    .trigger-filter[data-filter='all'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='customer-success'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='back-office'] img.checked-circle {
      background: #86278b;
    }

    .trigger-filter[data-filter='management'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='finance'] img.checked-circle {
      background: #b1e6ea;
    }

    .trigger-filter[data-filter='tarya-ukraine'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='business-development'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='customer-service'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='underwriting'] img.checked-circle,
    .trigger-filter[data-filter='tarya-holding'] img.checked-circle {
      background: #4e4d4b;
    }

  }


  @media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 767px) {

    .team:first-of-type(1) {
      top: 13px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(2) {
      top: 55px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(3) {
      top: 135px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(4) {
      top: 205px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(5) {
      top: 290px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(6) {
      top: 380px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(7) {
      top: 430px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(8) {
      top: 510px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(9) {
      top: 586px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(10) {
      top: 628px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(11) {
      top: 708px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(12) {
      top: 778px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(13) {
      top: 863px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(14) {
      top: 953px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(15) {
      top: 1003px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(16) {
      top: 1083px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(17) {
      top: 1159px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(18) {
      top: 1201px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(19) {
      top: 1281px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(20) {
      top: 1351px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(21) {
      top: 1436px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(22) {
      top: 1526px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(23) {
      top: 1576px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(24) {
      top: 1656px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(25) {
      top: 1732px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(26) {
      top: 1774px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(27) {
      top: 1854px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(28) {
      top: 1924px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(29) {
      top: 2009px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(30) {
      top: 2099px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(31) {
      top: 2149px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(32) {
      top: 2229px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(33) {
      top: 2305px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(34) {
      top: 2347px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(35) {
      top: 2427px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(36) {
      top: 2497px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(37) {
      top: 2582px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(38) {
      top: 2672px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(39) {
      top: 2722px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(40) {
      top: 2802px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(41) {
      top: 2878px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(42) {
      top: 2920px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(43) {
      top: 3000px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(44) {
      top: 3070px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(45) {
      top: 3155px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(46) {
      top: 3245px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(47) {
      top: 3295px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(48) {
      top: 3375px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(49) {
      top: 3451px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(50) {
      top: 3493px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(51) {
      top: 3573px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(52) {
      top: 3643px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(53) {
      top: 3728px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(54) {
      top: 3818px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(55) {
      top: 3868px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(56) {
      top: 3948px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(57) {
      top: 4024px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(58) {
      top: 4066px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(59) {
      top: 4146px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(60) {
      top: 4216px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(61) {
      top: 4301px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(62) {
      top: 4391px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(63) {
      top: 4441px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(64) {
      top: 4521px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(65) {
      top: 4597px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(66) {
      top: 4639px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(67) {
      top: 4719px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(68) {
      top: 4789px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(69) {
      top: 4874px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(70) {
      top: 4964px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(71) {
      top: 5014px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(72) {
      top: 5094px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(73) {
      top: 5170px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(74) {
      top: 5212px !important;
    }

    .team:nth-of-type(75) {
      top: 5292px !important;
    }


    .all-of-them {
      height: 5450px;
    }



    .team:nth-child(2),
    .team:nth-child(8n+2) {
      width: 27%;
      left: 52%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(4),
    .team:nth-child(8n+4) {
      width: 27%;
      left: 57%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(6),
    .team:nth-child(8n+6) {
      width: 20%;
      left: 58%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(8),
    .team:nth-child(8n+8) {
      width: 22%;
      left: 60%;
    }

    .team:first-child,
    .team:nth-child(8n+1) {
      width: 19%;
      left: 26%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(3),
    .team:nth-child(8n+3) {
      width: 27%;
      left: 19%;
    }

    .team:nth-child(7),
    .team:nth-child(8n+7) {
      width: 31%;
      left: 24%;
    }



  }
```

Any ideas how to get this done?

Comment: We kinda need your html and css in order to help you.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Added the basics - there's much more but the editor won't allow it. You can see the final result here: [link](http://outofsite.co.il/traya/team-he.html) - check it out in mobile mode, as the filters only appear in mobile, not in desktop.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you shared the html script too. 
But i guess you can use css "float" property to make what you want.
When "float :left;" is added to style of all your filter elements , they will start to shift to upper position when one of them is hidden.

this is a simple example based on my assumption for your html :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnFilter").click(function() {
    $('#item1').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerDiv" style="width:200px; height:100px; border:1px solid black; padding:1%">
  <div id="imageDiv" style="width:40%; border:1px solid black; float:left; height:100%"> image div</div>
  <div id="imageDiv" style="width:40%; border:1px solid black; float:left; margin-left:5%; padding:5%; height:80%">
    <div id="item1" style="width:90%; height:20; border:1px solid black; float:left;">item 1</div>
    <div id="item2" style="width:90%; height:20; border:1px solid black; float:left; margin-top:5%">item 2</div>
    <div id="item3" style="width:90%; height:20; border:1px solid black; float:left; margin-top:5%">item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnFilter" value="Let be filter" style="margin-top:20px" />
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Not sure how this help's the OP's question since he is talking about that he needs to move all  the visible elements to the front, and they are ordered by position absolute.

Comment: don't know actually :). what i understand from his question he hides some element and empy spaces remain in the place of these elements. Therefore, i offered this solution to be able to shift other elements to empty spaces. but as you said we need his html and css.

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute position properties are `left` and `top`. So, you will know what the smallest possible value is for `top` and `left`. Define a `topInitial`, `leftInitial`, `topOffset` and a `leftOffset` variable which will contain the initial values and the difference between `top` and `left` of two subsequent elements to be displayed. Now, let's assume that you have a `visibleElements` variable holding the elements to be displayed. In this case, you can use this algorithm:

```
var currentTop = initialTop;
var currentLeft = initialLeft;
var current
for (var visibleElement of visibleElements) {
    visibleElement.css('left', currentLeft + 'px').css('top', currentTop + 'px');
    currentLeft += leftOffset;
    currentTop += topOffset;
}
```

Comment: thx! but not sure this would work, as the spaces between each absolute element are not the same...

Comment: @IdoAngel-Bohadana the idea above assumes that the spaces are the same indeed. If the spaces between elements depend somehow on your custom logic, then apply your custom logic to it in this case as well.